# Python Unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'range'

Tags: python, operador, integer

Llevo ya varios días tratando de que este código me corra.
Primero, a 'Q' tuve que agregarle el 'int()' y 'range()' porque me decía que float no era un objeto iterable.
Después de hacer los cambios ya comentados, obtengo este nuevo error y no sé cómo resolverlo.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'range'

El IDE me indica que el error está en 'rule 1' por lo que supongo el error viene desde más arriba.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.
El código es el siguiente :

```
def model3(T,mu,alpha,beta):
    d_3=np.zeros((3,3))
        
    
    for h in range (T):
        rew1=1
        rew2=1
        q1=0.5
        q2=0.5
        delta1=rew1-q1
        delta2=rew2-q2
        q1=q1+alpha*delta1
        q2=q2+alpha*delta2
        Q=range(int(q1+q2))
        rule1=math.exp(beta*q1)//sum(math.exp(beta*Q))
        rule2=math.exp(beta*q2)//sum(math.exp(beta*Q))
        p=[rule1,rule2] 
    #Make choice according to choice probailities
        c=random.choice(p)
    #Generated reward
        r_3=np.random.rand()
        d_3[0,1]=1
        d_3[0,2]=0
    
        if c==p[0]:       
            m_3=mu[0]     
            d_3[1,0]=k[0] 
        else:
            m_3=mu[1]     
            d_3[2,0]=k[1]  

    
    
        if r_3<m_3:
            reward_3=1    
            if m_3==mu[0]:          
                d_3[1,1]=d_3[1,1]+1
            else:
                d_3[2,1]=d_3[2,1]+1 
    
        else:
            reward_3=0
            if m_3==mu[0]:          
                d_3[1,2]=d_3[1,2]+1 
            else:
                d_3[2,2]=d_3[2,2]+1 
     
                    
    return(d_3)
```

Comment: Qué es beta? No conocemos nada de tu código, de qué datos usas para probarlo, etc. Trata de hacer más fácil el que entendamos cómo lo usas

Comment: Si nos dijeras en que línea está el error seria un gran avance ...

Answer (score 0):

Escribes

```
Q=range(int(q1+q2))
rule1=math.exp(beta*q1)//sum(math.exp(beta*Q))
```

donde `Q` es un `range`, una *secuencia inmutable*. No es una lista ni un escalar, sino otra cosa, pensada para usar en iteraciones.

Entonces, en la segunda línea, quieres hacer `beta * Q`, donde la primera variable es un entero. Eso no es válido ni tiene sentido.

Mirando el resto de la expresión `sum(math.exp(beta*Q))` pareciera que espera una lista de valores, pero `math.exp` retorna un valor escalar y también espera un valor escalar como parámetro, así que nada calza: no tiene sentido hacer `sum()` de un sólo valor.

No está claro la lógica detrás de tus cálculos.